# How to use Bosch LRR3 using the Bosch package?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How can I incorporate the bosch lrr3 radar into ros?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/44069/how-to-use-bosch-lrr3-using-the-bosch-package?/) by [fuzail](https://answers.ros.org/users/3223/fuzail/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-09-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dejanpan](https://answers.ros.org/users/92/dejanpan/) on 2012-09-22**:
Sorry maybe I misunderstood the question, do you already have some code that can talk to the device? In that case wrapping it into the ROS node is really trivia and we would be happy to help. D.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there, I am one of the admins of the bosch-ros-pkg. Our personal robotics group at Bosch Research unfortunately does not have a ROS driver for LRR3 yet. If there is a greater demand for it, maybe we could try and get from our business unit. Can you send me a private message regarding this?

---

Originally posted by [dejanpan](https://answers.ros.org/users/92/dejanpan/) with karma: 1420 on 2012-09-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0